How to convert video to audio using react-native expo
I want to convert video files of any extension to mp3 using expo react-native.
Successfully convert video of any extension to audio (mp3) or other audio types.
I have tried using expo-av but that did not work as expected.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
